# Remove duplicate words except numbers

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, methods

I need to remove duplicate words in a string, but not the numeric characters.

Here's an example of text that I need to convert and keep the numeric characters.
Any suggestions on how to handle this?

String example: "Rim - Rim Black 28H 700mm x 700mm"

```
  static removeDuplicateWords = (statement: string) => {
    return statement
      .split(" ")
      .filter((item, pos, self) => {
        return self.indexOf(item) === pos;
      })
      .join(" ");
  };
```

Current Results: - Rim Black 28H x 700mm

Expected results: - Rim Black 28H 700mm x 700mm

Thanks for the help

Comment: `700mm` is not a number, since it has `mm` in it. Do you mean anything that starts with a number?

Comment: Sorry, I mean something that contains numeric characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression to test if the word contains a digit.

```js
static removeDuplicateWords = (statement: string) => {
  return statement
    .split(" ")
    .filter((item, pos, self) => item.match(/\d/) || self.indexOf(item) === pos)
    .join(" ");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, you can create a set of the split string and join it again.

```js
console.log(Array.from(new Set("Rim - Rim Black 28H 700mm x 700mm".split(' '))).join(' '))

// print 'Rim - Black 28H x 700mm'
```